Error handling json: invalid char in json text
I am using the jsonlite library that should work well with the json file format that jspsych outputs in.
I am trying to read all of the files within a folder into a single R dataframe.
Here is the code I'm using:
library(jsonlite)
dataset <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
{  
  cat(i," ") 
  temp_data <- fromJSON(file_list[i])  
  dataset <- rbind(dataset, temp_data) 
}
head(dataset)

I got the error message:
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       subject-64518a37ad8eb.json
                     (right here) ------^

Anyone can help me solve this issue please?

You would need to show us the contents of the JSON file, at least the part containing the error.  Was that really all of the detail that the error message contained?  I would expect it to contain at least one line quoted from the file, with that "^" pointing to the exact location of the problematic character.

@jasonharper Actually, that is all I got Errore: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
subject-64518a37ad8eb.json
(right here) ------^

It appears to be trying to parse the filename as JSON, and not reading a file at all.  I'm not familiar with R, so I don't know if there's some alternative to fromJSON() that actually takes a filename, or if you're expected to read the file yourself and pass that to the function.
